# What am I doing wrong? (C programming, pointers, structs, functions)

Tags: c, pointers

I am unsure if my use of malloc is correct, but what bother's me is the inability to pass the struct into the put_age() function pointer. It looks right to me but apparently it isn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
  int age;
  // NPC methods
 int (*put_age)(NPC *character, int age);
} NPC;

////////////////////////////////////

int set_age(NPC *character, int age);

int main(){
  NPC *zelda = malloc(sizeof(NPC));
  zelda->put_age = set_age;
  zelda->put_age(zelda, 25);
  printf("Zelda's age is %d\n", zelda->age);

  return 0;
}

int set_age(NPC *character, int age){
  character->age = age;     
  return 0;
}
```

COMPILER OUTPUT:

```
$ gcc ~/test.c
/test.c:7:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/test.c:8:1: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
/test.c: In function ‘main’:
/test.c:16:8: error: ‘NPC’ has no member named ‘put_age’
/test.c:17:8: error: ‘NPC’ has no member named ‘put_age’
```

Comment: please copy&paste exactly instead of hand copying. Are you going to tell us what the problem is?

Comment: @GregS How do you know he didn't? It looks like a complete code snippet to me.

Comment: @GregS:  What's the difference?

Comment: zelda->age in set_age() shouldn't compile, right?

Comment: @GregS Assumably, that's what he's asking about.

Comment: zelda is local to main, you cannot use it in set_age. use the `NPC * character` in set_age in the place of `zelda`

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I changed the source and posted compiler errors. I have fought with these errors for quite a long time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is that `NPC` isn't the name of a type until the declaration of the `struct` `typedef` is complete. You can change this by giving the struct a name, e.g.

```
typedef struct tagNPC {
  int age;
  // NPC methods
  int (*put_age)(struct tagNPC *character, int age);
} NPC;
```

or

```
typedef struct tagNPC NPC;

struct tagNPC {
  int age;
  // NPC methods
  int (*put_age)(NPC *character, int age);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this nailed the main problem I had been fighting with.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use typedef "NPC" inside the struct def. That's because until the compiler has not seen the closing "}" , it has no idea what NPC is.

Please try changing:

```
typedef struct{
  int age;
  // NPC methods
 int (*put_age)(NPC *character, int age);
} NPC;
```

to:

```
typedf struct node_npc NPC;

struct node_npc
{
    int age;
    int (*put_age)(NPC *character, int age);
};
```

Comment: :) yw. new to this site, so don't know how to use it properly, but love this site. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
int set_age(NPC *character, int age){
  zelda->age = age;     
  return 0;
}
```

To:

```
int set_age(NPC *character, int age){
  character->age = age;     
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to change that in my test code. I changed it and still get compiler errors. I edited my first post with the compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

In `set_age()`, your variable's name is `character`, not `zelda`, so the code should be:

```
int set_age(NPC *character, int age){
  character->age = age;     
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code. I had forgot about that, that was an older mistake while I was testing code.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem, when I had a constant defined someware in my code that was named like a member of a struct. Ex.

```
#define N 10 

struct my_struct{
    int N;
};
```